# How to calculate a record's ranking compared to others based on a single column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Assuming I have `User` model with a column called `point`.

How can I get an instance's ranking compared to all other `User` rows.

Answer (score 2):

The user's rank can be thought of as the number other users with more points than them, plus 1. As Mischa pointed out in the comments, an appropriate place for this would be in the User model itself, as in:

```
def ranking
   User.where('point > ?', point).count + 1
end
```

You would then call it as:

```
Rank: <%= @user.ranking %>
```

This has the downside of ranking users with the same number of points at the same rank. You'll have to decide on a "tiebreaker" for that case.

Comment: This shouldn't be a helper method, but an instance method on the user model, allowing you to do `@user.ranking`. Other than that, good idea.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, I've changed my answer to do that.