# ActiveRecord (Rails 4) determine index of record in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I'm trying to do is determine what rank a sales person came in for a month as far as earning commission goes in the least amount of steps possible. I think it might be possible to do with a combination of ActiveRecord + some enumerable methods, but essentially I have a model that looks like the following:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :commission, presence: true
end
```

`commission` is just an integer. So in order to get all employees ordered from highest to lowest for commission earned, we can do something as trivial as:

`Employee.order('commission desc')`

My question is, assume that the `employee` I'm looking for has an id of `50`. What's an easy way of knowing what "rank" they are in as far as commission earned. If they are at the top of the list, they have earned a rank of #1. If they are last in the descending sort, their rank is ultimately the size of `Employee.all.count`

Employees who share the same commission amount should be ranked the same. Multiple employees sharing a rank is correct.

Comment: How would you rank two (or more) employees that share the same commission amount?

Comment: Good question. They can share the same rank. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have any native ranking functions, so you'll need to [resort to the GROUP_CONCAT method](http://de.planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=21183) to get this to work efficiently:

```
Employee.
  select('employees.*, FIND_IN_SET(commission, ranks) AS rank').
  joins(', (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT commission, ORDER BY commission DESC) AS ranks FROM employees) ranks').
  order('commission desc')
```

You can also use the self-join approach commonly used, but performance will likely degrade significantly as the table grows.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just count how many employees had higher commissions:

```
Employee.where('commission > ?', Employee.find(50).commission).count + 1
```

credit to:

[How to calculate a record's ranking compared to others based on a single column in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697957/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-rank-of-arrays-in-ruby)

The downside with that literal approach is two queries, but the id lookup should be fast, if it's not already cached or otherwise available, e.g., if you had already instantiated an object for that employee from which you could just get the commission without another query.

Comment: Another downside is that this gives you the rank for a _single_ employee.  If you want the rank for multiple employees, you'll have to call this for _every one_.  Not very scalable...

Comment: And lastly, this doesn't quite yield correct results for the interpretation of 'rank' being used.  If the commissions are (in descending order) `[40, 30, 30, 25, 25, 20, 10]`, an employee with a commission of 20 should be ranked 4th - but this algorithm will yield 6.  However, this problem can be addressed using `.count('DISTINCT commission')`

Comment: The question asked how to find the rank of a certain employee, but I take your point. On the second item, 6 is the right answer in your example. Typically if two people tie for first place, the next person is considered to have come in third, not second. So the right ranks in your example are 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6 ,7. Getting that right is actually an advantage of this method.

Comment: I stand corrected on that second point - your interpretation is indeed how RANK() functions are implemented (in SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle).  My interpretation (and the one in the article I linked to) is how DENSE_RANK() is typically implemented.  Removing DISTINCT would solve that problem.